# Latex with http / lighttpd

Tags: linux, latex

I'm using Imgtex with Apache to solve latex equations on Ubuntu, but my all the other boxes are on centos and want to migrate imgtex/latex server to centos for uniformity.

Imgtex is not available for centos.

My question is how can we configure latex with httpd or lighttpd on centos or any other redhat flavor.

Comment: You don't solve equations with LaTeX, you just display them!

Answer (score 2):

According to its [web page](http://www.eaflux.com/imgtex/), `imgtex` is just a script written in Perl providing a FastCGI service. You can configure `lighttpd` to [enable FastCGI](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI). So I think you should be able to make `imgtex` work on your system.

You could also consider other solutions, notably [HeVeA](http://hevea.inria.fr/), to translate latex math equations into images or HTML.

Comment: thanks, yes, i tried copying file imgtex.fcgi and tried to execute via lighttpd, i didnt get any errors though but equation were not forming.

Comment: Thanks was able to configure imgtex on centos, to be in brief get imgtex.fcgi and preverr.png, place in cgi folder. Create a folder imgtexwork with 777 permission and use url http://localhost/cgi-bin/imgtex.fcgi. Other packages to install before above steps include tetex-latex, dvipng.

Comment: I suggest that a directory with a 777 permission could be a security risk. You can give less permissions to it (perhaps by changing its owner to the id of the web process).